# react native map triggers NFCReaderUsageDescription?

Tags: react-native, testflight

I have made a simple react native app using map view. it just have some simple functionality. I uploaded it to iOS testflight to setup our team testings. but it got rejected becuase of using NFC??

`Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NFCReaderUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.`